# Decrypting WiFi password with Win XP regedit file?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wireless-networking, regedit

I'm having problem with decrypting Windows XP wireless password (WPA2), I am supposed to retrieve WPA2 password from regedit file which I have already recovered from a formatted partition.

I have recovered some registry files (regedit) from the formatted system partition (C:) of the Windows XP OS.

Based on these registry files I would like to obtain Wi-Fi password that was stored in some branches of registry.

I know that Windows XP stores Wi-Fi keys in the following reg:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WZCSVC\
```

I did find it, but it's encrypted, how can I possibly decrypt this key in order to obtain the actual password ?

I tried to import entire registry file to newly installed Win XP but I failed, since I can't read the password from WZCSVC. What type of encryption does Win XP uses to store these passwords in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WZCSVC\` ?

Maybe there is some ready-made software that can help me out with this, apart from Wireless KeyView which is unable to read any password from the registry, unless it's currently in use...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the password and the encrypted password file, it IS possible to decrypt.

If not, you could use the encrypted password in the application that uses it. And retrieve the password before it is being red.

You stated that *you tried Wireless KeyView* and that *there's no application that can use this file*.

Decrypting something without knowing the encryption scheme. Without knowing the password, the only solution would be to use a brute force cracker to guess the password. As long as the password isn't long, there's some chances of retrieval.

You can use JohnnyTheRipper, it's a traditional tool to guess passwords and there are a few dictionaries that can be downloaded.

You could also try to find a hidden password file somewhere in your system. There are free third party software available for this task.

Hacking a Wireless Router is easy. There are many topics on it. The encryption scheme isn't secure and it's a common problem in home security.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cain and Abel, it has the ability to dump your local wifi keys as well as LSA's

http://www.oxid.it/cain.html

from site: Cain & Abel is a password recovery tool for Microsoft Operating Systems. It allows easy recovery of various kind of passwords by sniffing the network, cracking encrypted passwords using Dictionary, Brute-Force and Cryptanalysis attacks, recording VoIP conversations, decoding scrambled passwords, recovering wireless network keys, revealing password boxes, uncovering cached passwords and analyzing routing protocols. The program does not exploit any software vulnerabilities or bugs that could not be fixed with little effort. It covers some security aspects/weakness present in protocol's standards, authentication methods and caching mechanisms; its main purpose is the simplified recovery of passwords and credentials from various sources, however it also ships some "non standard" utilities for Microsoft Windows users.

Answer (score -1):

WirelessKeyView can access external Windows/Registry files. If you can mount the old drive, that's the easiest way. If not, and you have the registry hive file, you simply need to recreate the directory layout.

Place the software hive in `C:\RandomDirectory\System32\Config\Software` and point WirelessKeyView to `C:\RandoomDirectory\` and it should work.